# How to clicking on multiple buttons using click()

Tags: python, selenium

Writing a scraping project and having a problem with clicking a list with "a-tags". I have collected the "a-tags" but can't click on them using a for-loop. It seems like the `click()` function breaks because the first button is the only one that gets clicked.

Code:

```
driver.get(url)  
try:
    myElem = None 
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href ='javascript:;']")))
    
    if myElem != None:
        buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href ='javascript:;']")
        # "find_elements_by_class_name("open")" filters out the "a-tags"
        buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("open")
        for button in buttons:
            button.click()
```

HTML ():

```
<a class="open" data-path="/public/employees/767772/description.json" href="javascript:;">
                <span class="icon-caret-right"></span> 続きを読む
</a>
```

Comment: What do your buttons do? Is it possible that after clicking the first button, the other ones disappear or are not visible anymore? Do you get an error message?

Comment: the program just stops and no error message. The buttons have a hide and visible mode. I have tested clicking them manually and you can open them all up at the same time.